# Let $a,b\in D_4$ and such that $ba=a^{3}b$. Prove that if $0\leq i<4$ and $0\leq j<2$, then $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$ also it is

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $a,b\in D_4$ and such that $ba=a^{3}b$. Prove that if $0\leq i<4$ and $0\leq j<2$, then $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$,(where $i,j,i_1,j_1\in \mathbb{Z}$) also it is given $o(a)=4$ and $o(b)=2$. $D_4$ is a dihedral group of order $8$.

I could only verify the fact that if $ba=a^3b$, then $\forall i\in \mathbb {Z}$, $ba^i=a^{3i}b$. This is because $ba^i=baa^{i-1}=a^3ba^{i-1}=a^3baa^{i-2}=a^6ba^{i-2}$. Then, continuing on this way, we have, $a^{3i}b=ba^i$. But I dont know how to prove $a^ib^ja^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i+3i_1}b^{j+j_1}$?